# Coin Change - Finding maximum Number

Tags: java, max, knapsack-problem

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to explain this problem.  I'm currently trying to create a program for extra credit in my programming class, but I don't even understand the math behind it....  So I would love if someone could help me out. Alright:

Say you have 1 cent coin and a 4 cent coin.  And the total number of coins allowed is 4.  The **maximal coverage** of the value is 11.  The chart is below.

```
Value | 1 cent | 4 cent
 1    | 1
 2    | 2
 3    | 3
 4    | 4
 5    | 1      | 1
 6    | 2      | 1
 7    | 3      | 1
 8    |        | 2
 9    | 1      | 2
10    | 2      | 2
11    | Maximum
```

S0 that's an example.  I need to make this for something that is a much larger number.  But I would love if someone can help explain the math for me.  Or what the equation is... It's driving me insane.

I was trying to implement a version of the knapsack algorithm, but it doesn't seem to be doing the trick.  If anyone can help it would be much appreciated.  I'm not sure if I'm able to do that or if I need to use the greedy algorithm for this solution.  It's basically a twist on the greedy algorithm.

EDIT: changed to 11

Comment: What do you mean by "maximal coverage"? And how do you get the number 13? Is it given?

Comment: This problem requires understanding of [Dynamic Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) . A good tutorial on [TopCoder](http://www.topcoder.com/tc?d1=tutorials&d2=dynProg&module=Static) also.

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant 11.  It was a typo.  I just fixed it.  Well Ajmartin below suggested looking at understanding dynamic programming, so I'm currently looking at that.  So it's basically the continuous number until it hits zero.   As code, I was looking at trying to do basically dividing the value V by the largest coin you have in your array D[] then adding that many of D[i] to your array which holds the coins you're using to achieve the value
then just moving to the next denomination in D[] and repeating the operation until the remainder of the division is 0

Comment: I'm not sure if that would work though.

Answer (score 2):

Dynamic programming (DP) is the way to solve the problem. DP generally involves finding some basic property you can compute based on other values of that property -- a form of inductive reasoning.

In your case, the basic question you need to ask is: "can I make n cents using exactly k coins". That's a simple boolean yes/no; because you can reuse coins, you don't need to know *how* to make `n` cents with `k` coins, only whether it is possible. This implicitly defines a boolean matrix `A[n][k]`, where `A[n][k] = TRUE` iff you can make `n` cents with `k` of the given sorts of coins.

Study the relationships between the various entries in this truth table. For example, if I can make 5 cents with 2 coins, then it follows I can make 6 and 9 cents each with 3 coins (why?); thus `A[5][2]` implies `A[6][3]` and `A[9][3]`.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Note: I'm re-posting because the other answer was deleted while updating to provide more context.

[This](https://bitbucket.org/asraful/coin-change) appears to be the original problem author and his Java source code solution, if you'd like to study it further.

However, here's the summary of how this algorithm works, using dynamic programming:

**Assumptions:**
Each value in `T` is constrained by `Integer.MAX_VALUE`
`T` is constrained by `Integer.MAX_VALUE -1`

**Definitions:**
`D = {d1, d2, ..., dk}∀ d∈ℤ, ∀ w_d = 1`
`T = W = Total Weight of Knapsack = Total Coins Available for Use`

How the algorithm works:

1. Ensures `W > 0` and that by `1 ∈ D`
2. Ensures constraints above are met
3. Create a dynamically-sized array `MinCoins[0] = 0`
4. Let `n=1` and iterate by 1 as `n→∞`

   - For each iteration, set `MinCoins[ n ] = Integer.MAX_VALUE`
   - Iterate over each element in *D*, let each value be known as `d` during iteration

     - If `d > n` skip this iteration
     - Let `z` represent the optimal number of coins for this iteration
     - Get the optimal number of coins from the previous iteration, and add one more (of this value) to it: `z = MinCoins [ n - d ] + 1`
     - Now compare `z` to `MinCoins[ n ]`
     - If `z < MinCoins[ n ]` a new optimal solution has been found (save it), else iterate to next `d`
   - Let the optimal solution found for this iteration be defined as `q = MinCoins[ n ]`
   - If `q < T` then continue to next iteration. Else, no maximum solution was found this iteration and break the loop.

https://bitbucket.org/asraful/coin-change